# Filter or alert on some words or phrases when asking a question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, edits

I am reviewing in queues for a while and most of my edit cases are a **good question** with a begging phrase like *Please help* or something like that.

I assume that everybody want to help here. So this phrases and words are not necessary or nice.

Shouldn't we add a minimum pre-check for this kind of words and phrases when someone is asking a question to prevent them (or at least some of them) in the future to save our reviewers time?

Comment: I'm not sure what time you're saying it would save? Or are you saying that someone submitted an edit, but didn't remove the noise? If so, and the edit is trivially fixing the post, you would likely be better off rejecting the post and editing it yourself, making as many improvements as possible; those that submit incomplete edits (like not removing noise) will soon learn, especially if they can't submit edits to the queue any more. The problem isn't so much that the system needs to block "I need help", but that editors needs to address *all* the problems of the question in their edit.

Comment: Cn U plz hlp me wit mi prblm, @RobertLongson ? :)

Comment: Maybe you don't find it important but the edit time itself and review time in suggested edits should be enough to prove a point. @Larnu

Comment: I didn't see it from that angle. I agree. @RobertLongson

Comment: @skyBlue the reviews aren't meant to be "quick". You're meant to be thorough; if that means taking 5 minutes to reject an edit and then make significant improvements to the post because the OP didn't use a single piece of formatting, then so be it. If you don't want to take that time, skip that particular review.

Comment: From my perspective you are just resisting against what is against your opinion. Some questions are just 3 lines and they can and will be quickly reviewed. some are filled with i istead of I and it is ridiculous. @Larnu

Comment: And if you come up against one of those questions, where the user doesn't use proper capitalisation, you should edit it to improve it, @skyBlue . I don't know why you're against that. It it nonsense to stop a user typing i instead of I; there could be a multitude of legitimate reasons they need to use a lowercase i.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This isn't a good idea, we'd just end up with people writing plz hlp or some whack-a-mole variant instead, or they'd spell it with a zero width character in there somewhere. This already happens with [problem becoming probelm etc.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112944/the-title-word-filter-is-one-of-the-worst-ideas-ever-implemented-on-so) as problem is currently and pointlessly banned.